# Is there any way to use trackpad force touch for right click?

Tags: trackpad

I see there is no option to select force touch for secondary click in System Preferences. But for me it would have been perfect option for the right click.
I could not find anything about this in google, maybe there is some hack to make right click work from force touch?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, that I know of, to achieve the desired result:

You can use a paid app called [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) and map force touch to right click.

Alternatively, you can use the free and open source app [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) and write a script using [hs.eventtap.rightClick](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html#rightClick). You can draw inspiration from the [ForceTouchMapper spoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/Spoons/ForceTouchMapper.html).